# Journey Builder - How to update a specific related record to a contact with update activity

Tags: marketing-cloud, journeybuilder, update

Looking for some help here, we are stuck -

Background:
We have a Journey that is triggered by an opportunity data extension. Contacts can have multiple opportunities and multiple opportunities can be in the journey at any given time.

Our problem:
We need to update our opportunity data extension for each opportunity that is 'active' inside of the journey (Journey_Status field). However, the update activity in the journey updates every record with the same contact email_address, not only the record that is in the journey. How can we stamp only the opportunities that have actually entered into the journey with an 'Active' status?

Thanks!

Comment: In theory you should be able to achieve this using Mustache and [Data Binding](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.mc-apis.meta/mc-apis/how-data-binding-works.htm). I can provide the syntax that you require if you can clarify (a) the name of your Event Source DE, (b) the DE where the Journey_Status field exists, (c) whether the Event Source DE is a Population or an Attribute Group in your Contact Model. Also is the 'Journey_Status' field empty for Contacts that are not active? Or do you have another value in here like 'inactive'?

Comment: I am having the same issue. My idea is just using AMPscript to update the related record when sending emails/SMS, but it's not the perfect solution. Were you able to solve the problem?